# Gitolite SSH URL Format

Tags: ssh, unix, git, gitolite

So I got [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/) set up. Simple. But there is one issue I am having. The SSH urls follow the format of `git@host:repo`. I'm used to [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org) / [Github](http://github.com) where the urls follow the format of `git@host:user/repo`. Is there a way to get the latter format using [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/)?

Another question. I have my `~/.ssh/config` file set up with the following entry:

```
Host <host>
User <user>
IdentityFile <path/to/public/key>
```

I don't have any configuration specifying `git` as a user, and yet I am able to clone `git@host:repo` without problem. Obviously, my ssh client is using my public key to access the server which is why [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/) is letting me clone the repo, but how does my ssh client know to use my public key which is only configured for the `<user>` user and not the `git` user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Gitolite and ssh](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/glssh.html)

> Restricting users to specific commands is very important for gitolite.
>   If you read [`man sshd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd) and look for authorized_keys file format, you'll see a lot of options you can add to the public key line, which restrict the incoming user in various ways. In particular, note the `command=` option, which means "regardless of what the incoming user is asking to do, forcibly run this command instead".
>
> Also note that when there are many public keys (i.e., lines) in the authorized_keys file, each line can have a different set of options and `command=` values.
>
> Without this `command=` option, the ssh daemon will simply give you a shell, which is not what we want for our gitolite keys (although we may well have other keys which we use to get a shell).
>
> **This is the backbone of what makes gitolite work; please make sure you understand this**.

Those `command=` are using the name of your public key as the user name.

So all your ssh queries are done with:

- the user git
- a public key whose name is registered in the parameters of the command= directive in the `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

As for `user/repos`, the closest you would have with Gitolite is in [wild repos and repo pattern](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/wild.html).

```
repo    CREATOR/a[0-9][0-9]
```